# How to disable ServiceStack page when accessing from web browser

Tags: servicestack

When I open my API in web browser, I get following interface.
[image]

I have to click "json" to see the returned raw data.

How can I disable this UI and show the raw data in web browser directly without adding the `format` url query string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not seeing data returned from your Service as your Service is only returning an error.

### Disable Auto Html Pages

You can disable the [Auto Html Page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/HTML5ReportFormat) by removing the Html Feature in your AppHost Configure():

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    EnableFeatures = Feature.All.Remove(Feature.Html),
});
```

In browsers this will typically return XML results as browsers will ask for `application/xml` not JSON, to show JSON you can remove XML as well, e.g:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    EnableFeatures = Feature.All.Remove(Feature.Html | Feature.Xml),
});
```